# NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 occurring with image tag

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XSL sheet that returns everything fine, and I output it in an empty `div` in my HTML file.

If I use

```
<i class="material-icons circle">folder</i>
```

it works fine, but if I try instead to do

```
<img src="images/yuna.jpg" alt="" class="circle">
```

I get this error:

```
NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
```

Below is the code with the line I actually want to use commented out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
     <body>
        <ul class="collection">
           <xsl:for-each select="lfm/tracks/track">
              <xsl:sort  order="descending" data-type="number" select="playcount"/>
              <li class="collection-item avatar">
                 <i class="material-icons circle">folder</i> -
                 <!-- <img src="images/yuna.jpg" alt="" class="circle">-->
                 <span class="title">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                 </span>
                 <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="artist/name"/>
                 </p>
                 <p>
                    Playcount: 
                    <xsl:value-of select="playcount"/>
                 </p>
                 <!--<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">grade</i></a>-->
              </li>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
     </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What happens when  you try `<img src="images/yuna.jpg" alt="" class="circle" />`? At the moment, it would not be well-formed XML as the `img` tag is not closed.

Comment: This does work great! thanks @TimC